# Minor typos with the new Area51 changes

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

The voting system on Area51 [was overhauled today](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3038/announcement-changes-to-area-51-voting), which also came with some changes to the user interface.  I was told to dump all the typos I found into a list here:

1. On the profile pages for the main Area 51 site, the text for up and down votes is reversed:
   [Area 51 Main Profile Votes http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/-1222976946.png](http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/-1222976946.png)
2. On the tooltip for proposals in the definition stage, the new text for questions remaining has a typo ("ore" -> more):

[image: Definition Objectives Remaining]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Fixed.
2. Fixed.

Good eye – thanks.